# Meaning of L-reduction from Dominating set problem

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, approximation-algorithms, graph-domination

We are working in a variation of Locating dominating sets. Recently, we realized that the reduction from dominating set to our problem in proving its NP-completeness turns out to be also an L-reduction. This would mean that there is no PTAS for our problem since the dominating set problem does not have PTAS.  Now we have two questions:

1. since the dominating set problem is W[2]-complete, does that follow to our problem because of the L-reduction?
2. we have proved that our problem is in XP (i.e, piecewise polynomial) and also in APX (there is a 2-approximation polynomial algorithm). But dominating set problem is known to be not in APX. Does this mean somewhere we might have gone wrong or is this perfectly alright?

Comment: (1)  I'd say that it depends.  L-reductions allow some leeway between the upper and lower bounds of solution sizes (the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ constants), whereas W[2]-hardness reductions use an exact value of $k$.  If your proof show that G has a dom-set of size at most k iff your instance has solution size at most f(k) for some function f, then W[2]-hardness should hold.  (2)  APX membership is preserved between minimization problems, so if you have a minimization problem, something might be wrong.  But if you have a maximization problem, you might still be OK.

Comment: @ManuelLafond Ours is a minimization problem and we have proved it to be APX complete by L-reduction from Dominating set-B (graphs bounded by vertex degree B, i.e, $\Delta(G)=B$ ) problem. In proving W-hardness, f(k) is generally like k or k+1 or k+2 and so on. Any idea how much can we stretch that f(k)? Can it be as big as something like $2*k$ or say $\Delta*k$? Thank you for the response!

Comment: DomSet-B is in APX, assuming B is a constant. So there seems to be no contradiction with the L-reduction.  For W-hardness, you can stretch k to any function f(k) not depending on $n$.  So $2k$ or even $2^{2^k}$ is fine but not $\Delta k$ unless $\Delta$ is bounded by $k$.  Also, I don't know if DomSet-B is actually W[2]-hard - make sure this is the case if you reduce from that variant.